# How ffill a dataframe forward four times with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So if I have a dataframe like such:

```
  A  B  C
  1  1  1
  2  2  2
  3  3  3
```

I want to achieve this:

```
  A   B   C
  1   1   1
  1   1   1
  1   1   1
  1   1   1
  2   2   2
  2   2   2
  2   2   2
  2   2   2
  3   3   3
  3   3   3
  3   3   3
  3   3   3
  3   3   3
```

I know that this will probably involve ffill and the general process as describes in my question, but if there is a simpler way to do this, I'm perfectly happy with that. I just want the quickest and easiest way, because my script will be repeating this many times.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is `repeat` not `ffill`

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(4))
Out[63]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
0  1  1  1
0  1  1  1
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
1  2  2  2
1  2  2  2
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
2  3  3  3
2  3  3  3
2  3  3  3
```